# Trying to print a variable stored in another object java

Tags: java, object

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class player_test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner s_in = new Scanner(System.in);
     Scanner i_in = new Scanner(System.in);

     class player {

        String player_name;
        String player_class;
        String player_race;
        int player_STR = 10;
        int player_DEX;
        int player_CON;
        int player_WIS;
        int player_INT;
        int player_CHA;

    }

    int tempDex = new player(player_STR);
    System.out.println(tempDex);

  }
}
```

Alright, so I'm pretty new to java and I think this is more basic than I am making it out to be. So I have object player, that stores the player core stats in it, but how do I call on those variables at other points throughout the code? At least make it print the players strength score?

Comment: You can do `System.out.println(tempDex.player_STR);` or use your IDE to add a `toString()` method to `Player` btw you don't need to add `player_` to all the field names.

Comment: You should try to use `PascalCase` for classes and `camelCase` for variable/property/function names. It's a stylistic choice, of course, but that tends to be the most common way of naming things.

Comment: Watch out: int tempDex = new player(player_STR); you're assigning a player class to an int type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since all the variables in class **player** are non-static,so you need to create the object of this class to access its non-static data members.

```
int tempDex=new player(player_STR); //this will generate compilation error
```

Here you are creating a object of **player** class.so you should keep the tempDex of **player** type (can be super class too).
Secondly,you are using a parameterized constructor which is not defined in the class.So the proper way to do it is like this.....

```
player tempDex=new player(); // an Object of class player is created
System.out.println(tempDex.player_STR);
System.out.println(tempDex.player_Name);
// and so on.
```

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to create public methods that expose the internal state of your object that should be visible from other classes and leave not visible informations that should not be used by other classes.

Generally those methods are called getters and use the following syntax:

```
public String getPlayer_name() {
    return player_name;
}
```

Then in the second class you can print it very simply:

```
// is a best practice to start class names with uppercase
Player x = new Player();

... // Do something

System.out.println(x.getPlayer_name());
```